# communicating with slack using jslack's RTM library

Tags: java, slack-api, slack

am trying to use jslack: https://github.com/seratch/jslack RTM library to send and receive messages. But am not sure why `rtmClient.sendMessage("Hello WOrld");` isn't sending the message to slack bot, though it is able to successfully connect to the bot.
Please let me know, where am getting wrong.

```
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        try (RTMClient rtmClient = new Slack().rtm("xoxwerq-12632550058135")) {

            rtmClient.addMessageHandler((message) -> {
                JsonObject json = jsonParser.parse(message).getAsJsonObject();
                if (json.get("type") != null) {
                  log.info("Handled type: {}", json.get("type").getAsString());
                  //System.out.println("working");
                }
              });

              RTMMessageHandler handler2 = (message) -> {
                  log.info("Hello!");
                  //Logger.debug("client connected to the server: {}", wssUri);

                 // System.out.println("got it");
                  };

                 //rtmClient.addMessageHandler(RTMMessageHandler messageHandler);

                  rtmClient.addMessageHandler(handler2);

                  // must connect within 30 seconds after issuing wss endpoint
                  try {
                    rtmClient.connect();
                    rtmClient.sendMessage("Hello WOrld");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                    System.out.println("Bot started!!!!!!");
                    //rtmClient.addMessageHandler(handler2);
                    //Thread.sleep(5000);

                } catch (DeploymentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 rtmClient.removeMessageHandler(handler2);
        }`
```

Comment: I hope this is not your real token :) If it is please disable it and remove it from this post.

Comment: You may want to add what errors / exceptions you get (if any).

Comment: No, thats not my real token...

Comment: Am not getting any errors as such, just the warnings as "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.github.seratch.jslack.common.http.SlackHttpClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.Bot started!!!!!!"

Comment: Am running it as java application, not on any local server though.....but it doesn't matter i guess...please let me know

Comment: log4j is a standard logger for Java. the warnings suggest that it has not initialized yet and is not working. I would suggest fixing that first. The jsslack library will probably produce some helpful log messages that will help you identify the cause behind your issue.

Comment: ok i will try to fix that issue first..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the sendMessage method is the one to use. I tried and it doesn't post message to the bot channel either.

Here is what I use to post a message to a specific channel. In the case of an answer to the bot, I just retrieve the channel id from the bot message:

```
 private void postMessage(String channel, String message) {
        try {
            // https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
            ChatPostMessageResponse postResponse =
                    slack.methods().chatPostMessage(ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().token(token)
                            .channel(channel).text(message).build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```